# Install Gallery 3 in Subdirectory of Wordpress

Tags: gallery

I tried to install Gallery 3 as a subdirectory in my WordPress folder and point a subdomain to it, but it doesn't work.  The gallery site comes up initially, but there is no theming to it and if I try to click on login I get a 404.  The URL that comes up when I click log in ends with "/index.php/login/ajax" which doesn't seem right.  Anyone else try to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you installed it in a subdirectory of WordPress.  Both WordPress and Gallery 3 will use virtual URLs in their domain, and with them both acting on the same folders, neither system knows what to do.

So you have `http://blog.url/` and `http://blog.url/gallery3/` which is also `http://g3.blog.url/`.

The subdomain will point to that folder without any problem ... `http://g3.blog.url/` will redirect to `http://blog.url/gallery3/` ... but `http://g3.blog.url/something` will redirect to `http://blog.url/gallery3/something`.

Logically, you'll think this will work, but both Gallery 3 and WordPress will try to eat this URL to pass it to the appropriate page.  WordPress will send `http://g3.blog.url/login/ajax` to `http://blog.url/index.php/login/ajax` because that's where it thinks you're trying to go.

My recommendation would be to *not* use a subfolder of the WordPress directory for Gallery 3.  Put it in a separate folder altogether and point your subdomain there.  Then tell WordPress to reference the subdomain rather than the subfolder.  You won't run into `.htaccess` collisions that way.